# Removing BOM marker at the start of XML file

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I have an XML file, from which I am trying to remove a BOM as I need to parse it using lxml. A link to the file can be found [here](http://%20https://filebin.ca/5J7awcoUHzER). Some simplified code for this would be:

```
from lxml import etree

f = open(filename, "r")
ff = f.read()
fff = ff.encode('utf-8-sig')
ffff = fff.decode('utf-8')

tree = etree.fromstring(ffff)
```

I have tried to follow some of the examples on here for dealing with this sort of instance, however I am still getting the same error I started with:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? `etree.parse("m.tvguide.co.uk-full.channels.xml")` works for me.

Comment: No idea. Didn’t for me...

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is doing the encoding and decoding backwards, winding up with a doubled BOM instead of none at all. You want to encode with regular `utf-8`, and decode with `utf-8-sig`.

But you can avoid all that by doing the decoding right directly from the file. Try:

```
f = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
ff = f.read()

tree = etree.fromstring(ff)
```

Comment: hi - this now generates the following error: ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is now working:

```
f = open(nfile, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
ff = f.read()
fff = ff.encode("utf-8")


tree = etree.fromstring(fff)
```